# Pipenv Fatal Error Using "python\python36" After Upgrading to Python 3.7

Tags: python, windows-10, pipenv

I recently upgraded my python from 3.6.x to 3.7.4. Pipenv throws a "fatal error" whenever I try to use it. Ex:

```
pipenv install
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\smtro\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe"  "C:\Users\smtro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts\pipenv.exe" install'
```

Just trying to get pipenv running normally again.

Running on Windows 10-x64.
I've uninstalled and reinstalled both pip and pipenv. 
I've tried changing the environment variables for both the user and the system to touch \Python36, \Python37, and both.

```
python --version
Python 3.7.4
pip --version
pip 19.2.3 from c:\users\smtro\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, had to go to

```
c:\users\smtro\appdata\local\programs\python\
```

and manually delete \python36 directory because it was not removed in the upgrade. 
Reinstalling pipenv after this seems to have resolved the issue.